# Webpack function import not accessible by JS on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack-2

First time learning `webpack` with `Laravel 5.5`.

I have a `helpers.js` library which I include into my `app.js` bunlde like this:

```
import * as $mh from './helpers.js';
```

An example function in `helpers.js` is:

```
export function valRemoveHighlight(element)
{
    $(element).closest('.form-group, .input-group, .has-feedback').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
}
```

I can then access this function inside the bundle like this:

```
$mh.valRemoveHighlight(element);
```

But I have `JS` script at the bottom of my page which cannot access the function in the bundle. I have tried different scopes with no success:

```
window.$mh.valRemoveHighlight(element);
$mh.valRemoveHighlight(element);
valRemoveHighlight(element);
```

How do I make these exported / imported helper functions accessible in the global scope, so any inline / page script can access them?

Ideally kept within the helpers scope `$mh.` but accessible from the page / script like:

```
$mh.valRemoveHighlight(element);
```

Thanks!

Comment: this feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'd suggest your real issue is why do you need to access this outside of the bundle. Typically your either using `imports`/`exports` or your not. Trying to half way house it is what's causing your problems

Comment: you probably want to use a `window.onload` function, then you can keep it all inside webpack

Comment: Hi Liam, thanks for the suggestion. So do I pull it in inside window.onload the same way? window.$mh = $mh

Comment: No rather than trying to call `valRemoveHighlight` in the footer of your page, call `valRemoveHighlight` inside a `onload` event inside a script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$mh` is only available inside of app.js, so you will have to expose that function yourself inside your app.js by doing : `window.$mh = $mh`

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but I did not get you exactly. The JS code I need to be able to access the helpers is inline, on the page itself. How do I expose $mh to the whole page / global scope? Thanks

Comment: @TheRealPapa he's just told you how to do this? `window.$mh` is global scope.

Comment: @TheRealPapa inside app.js add this line : `window.$mh = $mh`

Comment: Though that said, this essentially defeats the object of using webpack in the first place. It's a hack